# SSLHandshakeException api.facebook.com

Tags: android, facebook

Trying to write my first Android native app with Facebook login.

I am getting a SSLHandshakeException and I have not idea how to troubleshoot it.

My main activity inherits from FacebookActivity and does openSession() I get the Facebook loging but I cannot login (thats when I get the exception)

The "Key Hashes" in the Facebook app are the ones I got from my signed app's keystore.

```
public class MainActivity extends FacebookActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  this.openSession();
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

Stack trace:

```
12-02 21:37:29.711: E/HttpOperation.run(2088): class javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US) does not match SubjectName(OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign, OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3, OU="VeriSign, Inc.", O=VeriSign Trust Network) of signing certificate. [https://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?api_key=882a8490361da98xxxxxxxxxxx1ddc14d&email=nicoxxxx.xxxxxxxx%40gmail.com&format=JSON&method=auth.login&migrations_override=%7B%27empty_json%27%3A+true%7D&password=M*****4&sig=76b8a7f5xxxxxxxx052875b7b831f&v=1.0]
12-02 21:37:29.711: E/HttpOperation(2088): Encountered exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US) does not match SubjectName(OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign, OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3, OU="VeriSign, Inc.", O=VeriSign Trust Network) of signing certificate.
12-02 21:37:29.711: W/System.err(2088): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: IssuerName(OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US) does not match SubjectName(OU=www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign, OU=VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3, OU="VeriSign, Inc.", O=VeriSign Trust Network) of signing certificate.
12-02 21:37:29.711: W/System.err(2088):     at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:477)
```

Comment: What version of Android are you using? This is either a bug in the certificate validation code or some mixup on FB's part. Does it work from a browser?

Comment: It's seems to be the phone.  Must have installed something.  Because 2 differents accounts do NOT work on the phone and 2 same accounts work on another

Comment: It seems the two phones have different CA certificates installed. You can probably try to create a custom `TrustManager` for your app and work around it, but don't know if the FB SDK, etc. allows for this.